# Bitnami Django Stack hosting multiple websites?

Tags: apache, bitnami

I am currently using the Bitnami Django Stack tool to host one of my applications. Is it possible to host another application while my first application is still running?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is possible. This depends on the way you want to "present it to the public". I'll explain you the way to do it using Apache prefixes but let me know if it is otherwise.

So, basically, when you are using a Bitnami Django Stack you have an Apache that loads `mod_wsgi` which serves your python requests against your website. The way Bitnami tells Apache: "Hey, I got some Django data, please, serve it at `URL/Project`" is by adding some directives indirectly to the apache main configuration file, `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`. This file includes `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf`, which includes `opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project/conf/httpd-prefix.conf`.

What you must do in order to be able to serve a second Django project at, say, `URL/LawrenceRules`, is to, within `/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/`, perform a copy from the sample django project like this: `sudo cp -a /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/Project /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/LawrenceRules`.

Now, you will have a project named LawrenceRules. But it is not enough. You must substitute all `Project` matches within the resulting LawrenceRules project with `LawrenceRules`, so that all the configurations point to the right place. This can be achieved with the following one-liner:

`sudo egrep -R '\/opt\/bitnami\/apps\/django\/django_projects\/Project' /opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/LawrenceRules | grep -v Binary | awk '{print $1}' | cut -f1 -d":" | sort | uniq | sudo xargs sed -i 's/Project/LawrenceRules/g'`

Finally, open `/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/LawrenceRules/conf/httpd-app.conf` and edit the last two lines, rewriting `/Project` with `LawrenceRules`.

Now, you will have to tell Apache (remember that he only knows about the first project, named after Project and served at `URL/Project`. Open `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf` and add the following line:

`Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/django/django_projects/LawrenceRules/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"`

And you are ready to go! Second project enabled. Let me know if you wish to enable different configurations. I'll be glad to help here. And I am sorry about this brick!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You just need to create another Django project. Note that the location of the Django projects folder depends on the platform. The projects folder is located at installdir/apps/django/django_projects (on Linux and macOS) and C:\Users\USER\Bitnami DjangoStack Projects on Windows.

To create a new project you will need to:

- Start the Bitnami console

`cd installdir
./use_django`

- Go to the project folder depending on your platform and use `django_admin.py` to create a new project:

`django-admin.py startproject <PROJECT>`

- Create as many application as you wanted inside your project using the `manage.py` tool:

`python manage.py startapp <APP>`

- Restart Apache:

`sudo installdir/ctlscript.sh restart apache`

You should now be able to see your new application at http://localhost/PROJECT/APP

Notice that, this procedure only would work if you don't have changed any of the default Bitnami configuration.